# Attaching custom behaviour to elements using Polymer Behaviour /Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, polymer-1.0

I was thinking of modifying an existing website using polymer /jquery in a way that I can keep existing structure as it is and just add some logic using Jquery or Polymer to a set of elements say all the **anchor tags** will have on click feature to show an popover with form which can modify the existing look and content for that specific tag.

So the main concern is should I go with jquery (manipulating the Dom and using some third party libraries like watch.js and bottle.js to get 2-way binding and dependency injection ) or should I go ahead with creating a set of web-components and then replacing them in my website.

Is it possible to add custom behaviors to existing tags using polymer,if that can be done then I can use that as I have binding dependency injection inbuilt in polymer 1.0.

I mean this is similar to angular directives whereby we can attach a scope and set of methods to that element along with some styling and html code .

```
<div my-custom-behavior ></div>
//above sample will attach suppose a popover to my div with a form which can be submitted to change the values in that div element
```

Can something similar be done in Polymer 1.0 or jQuery ?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ is a good introduction to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your google is broken? See [here](http://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/) for the basics.